# cgroup limit reached - no space left on device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, cgroups

We have two servers running ubuntu 14.04 using docker. Every other month when starting or building a container we get the message:

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused     "process_linux.go:258: applying cgroup configuration for process caused 
\"mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/cf657a58a1382e62976b4d339946f07e8a40f22f18b52822f884834f78830806: no space left on device\""
```

The disks have still lots of space but `cat /proc/cgroups` gives this: (num_cgroups keeps increasing)

```
#subsys_name    hierarchy   num_cgroups enabled
cpuset  1   65805   1
cpu 2   65807   1
cpuacct 3   65803   1
blkio   4   65803   1
memory  5   65535   1
devices 6   65805   1
freezer 7   65803   1
net_cls 8   65803   1
perf_event  9   65803   1
net_prio    10  65803   1
hugetlb 11  65803   1
```

Restarting the server always helped so far but we don't want to restart a server every few months.

So I started some research and found a directory in the /sys/fs/cgroup/*/user path.
`/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/user/998.user` is itself holding 65662 subdirectories. All named somewhat like `36309.session` (the number increases)

Is there a ways to see what process is creating those cgroups?
I thought it was process 998, but that doesn't even exists.

Comment: You need to be looking at physical disk space and so "df -h /sys/fs/cgroup"

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem with AWS Batch. I have no solution but I found this discussion https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29638. It seems that the problem is some kind of leak in kernel and/or Docker.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. You probably have a lot of dangling images/containers
which is causing the cgroup of docker to run out of space. check it by:

> docker images -a

> docker ps -a

You need to clean it up. One solution is to remove all images/containers/etc that are not being used at the moment:

> docker system prune -a